# What is spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate? How does it work with batch interval

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am working with `spark 1.5.2`. I understand what a batch interval is, essentially the interval after which the processing part should start on the data received from the receiver.
But I do not understand what is `spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate`. From some research it is apparently an important parameter.

Lets consider a scenario. my batch interval is set to 60s. And `spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate` is set to 60*1000. What if I get 60*2000 records in 60s due to some temporary load. What would happen? Will the additional 60*1000 records be dropped? Or would the processing happen twice during that batch interval?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Property `spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate` applies to number of records **per second**.

The *receiver max rate* is applied when receiving data from the stream - that means even before batch interval applies. In other words you will never get more records per second than set in `spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate`. The additional records will just "stay" in the stream (e.g. Kafka, network buffer, ...) and get processed in the next batch.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I mean a max rate of `60*1000` and temporary load of `60*2000`. Your answer is not clear. What I understood is "processing will happen only once every 60s. But only with 1000*60 records each time. Additional records are processed in the next batch". Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, that is correct. With that rate stream receiver will push at most 60K records per minute to the Spark runtime. The rest will be read from stream in the following minute and processed in the next batch.

Comment: can we do this in Java / Scala program?